# __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_10 causing compile failure

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I have just built my project in a new iMac 10.10, xcode 6.1 it just get this error below:

```
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:54:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecAccessControl.h:43:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10, __IPHONE_8_0);
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/Availability.h:159:50: note: expanded from macro
'__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING'
    #define __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_osx, _ios) __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_osx
                                                 ^
<scratch space>:43:1: note: expanded from here
__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_10
^
```

It doesn't look like my project issue, since the project builds ok on my mac osx 10.9, xcode6.1.
, and apple has some api changes for osx 10.10 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/frameworks/Security.html.

I googled the error, and find another the link https://github.com/pipobscure/fsevents/issues/40, where someone else also met this error, and he solved the problem by re-installing command line tools.

But for my issue, I reinstalled xcode and command line tool. It doesn't work, and error still persists.

Has anybody also met this error, and how do you fix it?

Comment: The availability macro says something about `__MAC_10_10`, but the framework has `MacOSX10.9.sdk` in its path. That looks at least fishy to me. Are you using the latest OS X SDK as Base SDK?

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I am using 10.9 sdk, since in xcode6.1 SDKs, there are 10.10 and 10.9 sdk. but I am using MacOSX10.9 sdk.

Answer (score 1):

After using OSX SDK 10.10, this error doesn't exist.

Comment: What did you have to change or do in order to make the switch?

Comment: I didn't change any code, just change the build command, using "-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk".